# Installing dotnet Core on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to host my ASP.NET-Core WebApi on nginx on my ubuntu system version 16.04.

According to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.0-download.md) and [this](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu) documentation, I should enter the commands:

`curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg`

```
sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
```

However, the command  `curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg`  gives me the following error message:

(23) Failed writing body

[image]

Am I doing something wrong, or is the documentation wrong?

Update:
[image]

Thank you

Update:

I can execute the following commands:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg 
sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg 
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-trusty-prod trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'
sudo apt-get update
```

But when I enter  `sudo apt-get install dotnet-SDK-2.0.0`, I am getting the following errors:

[image]

Update:

[image]

Comment: You are trying to do this in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, of course you don't have a write permission here as a regular user.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelO. if I add a sudo infront of the command, Iam getting the same error

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Why adding `sudo`? Just go to your home directory. Btw, you had to add `sudo` after `|` if you wanted to do it in such place.

Comment: So you either are not in *your* home directory, or have a file `microsoft.gpg` having root privileges so it can't be overwritten, or don't have write permission in your directory. This command is working for me.

Comment: You are correct, I wasnt in my home directory. However, when I want to install the sdk : 'sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.0.0', I get the errors
E: Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-2.0.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-2.0.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-sdk-2.0.0'

Comment: Have you executed all commands from this manual?

Comment: I updated the question. Thank you very much for your effort

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install dotnet<TAB><TAB>` i.e. press TAB twice after `dotnet` and see which packages are showing

Comment: It's clearly showing 'dotnet-sdk-2.0.0'

Comment: Remove `vscode.listcurl` and `microsoft.gpg` (if it's here) from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, do `sudo apt-get update` and try again. Don't write irrevelant things to system directories.

Comment: The files are not in sources.list.d, I did the update but Iam still getting the same error..

Comment: Your listing shows that at least `vscode.listcurl` is there.

Comment: Right I already removed it some minutes ago, I forgot that. I updated my question so you can see the files inside of sources.list.d

Comment: Damn. Try to install some package. For example, `pdftk`. If it will be installed, I don't know anymore.

Comment: If youre itnerested, i found out what went wrong. Currently, there is no .NET Core SDK running on ARM processor. Therefore I have to build my application from my computer..